# Expose Azure Table Storage as OData

Tags: c#, wcf, azure-table-storage

I have an table in the Azure Table Storage populated with different implementations of the base TableServiceEntity. Does anybody howto expose this through OData? Are there some best practices available?

Answer (score 0):

the answer can be found in this article: [How to access table storage entities without knowing the schema](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/481afa1b-03a9-42d9-ae79-9d5dc33b9297/)
. Overriding the `ReadingEntity` event on the `TableServiceContext` will give you the opportunity to map the unknown datatypes to the available types. The article shows the exact code too.

Comment: Actually it answers another question. Namely, how to deserialize the saved entities. Right now I would like to expose the 'unknown' properties as atom/json or whatever... When I place a breakpoint in the ReadingEntity event it shows the correct atom xml in the args.Data (with the extra properties provided), only it never shows up as is in my webbrowser. Does anybody has the final tip for me? Cheers,
Rogier

Answer (score 0):

There is another solutation as well. Might be more complex but I use it it in one off my projects.

I have a table that has multiple different TableServiceEntities. But when I query the table, I .take(100) for example, I want all the different types at once.

This link has helped me quite a bit:

http://www.wintellect.com/Articles/Working%20with%20Azure%20Tables%20with%20Multiple%20Entity%20Schemas%20by%20Jeffrey%20Richter.pdf